# Restricting the SlickJS AsNavFor method to the child of a parent div

Tags: slick.js

I have a slider that is likely to be one of a few on a page. I want the AsNavFor to only effect the slider it is related to (both are within a parent div) Is this possible? The slider is built within the CMS so it is not practical to have them using separate IDs or Classes so specificity seems to be my best option but I am not working this out very well.

The slider can be seen here: https://futurepresent.agency/powerpoint-but-better/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. The `asNavFor` option also accepts a jQuery object, not just a class/ID string. See basic example below which uses the adjacent carousel as the `asNavFor` option:

```js
$(function() {
    $("section").each(function() {
        var section   = $(this);
        var carousels = section.find(".carousel");

        // Iterate through each carousel in this section - assuming there are always 2
        carousels.each(function(i, el) {
            if (i === 0) {
                // If this is the first carousel (index 0), use the next carousel in the jQuery object
                $(el).slick({
                    asNavFor: carousels.eq(1)
                })
            } else {
                $(el).slick();
            }
        })
    })
})
```

```css
img {
    max-width: 64px;
}

section:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=1:1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=1:2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=1:3" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=2:1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=2:2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=2:3" />
    </div>
</section>

<section>
    <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=3:1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=3:2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=3:3" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=4:1" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=4:2" />
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/64x64?text=4:3" />
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
```